# update c3p0 using maven

Tags: hibernate, maven, c3p0

I have a very specific maven/c3p0/hibernate related question. I have a web archive project that relies on c3p0 for connection pooling and have accidentally used the old c3p0 dependency (0.9.1) in my project.

I've only recently noticed my mistake and want to upgrade to the latest version, so I deleted the old dependency in my pom.xml and added the new one (com.mchange.cp3 instead).

Now after cleaning and building and running my project on my server, I notice it's still using the old version... Even deleting the old jar files will cause maven to redownload these and use them again.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=c3p0` in terminal (most IDE's also have their version of this, in Eclipse it'd be the `Dependency hierarchy` tab on pom.xml) and check if it's a transitive dependency of some other dependency you're including. If so, use `<exclude>` tags to refrain those dependencies from adding the old version into the JAR.

Comment: Oh thanks, I notice hibernate-c3p0 4.3.0 beta indeed depends on this version of c3p0, I guess it's not very wise to force hibernate to work with a newer version?

Comment: do upgrade c3p0. it is backward-compatible and newer versions of c3p0 will work great with whatever version of hibernate you are using.

Comment: Excluding c3p0 in the hibernate-c3p0 dependency did the trick, everything looks fine. Many thanks for the help and advice!